# Can route 53 used as domain direct with geo location?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, routes, amazon-route53

I am wondering if route 53 can be used as domain redirect when page loads?

Let's say if I have a domain name `www.domain.com` which is hosted in `usa` and anther domain named `www.domain.tw` which is hosted in taiwan.

With the `route 53 traffic management`, can I say if the end user in taiwan entered `www.domain.com` then it'll automatically redirect the page to `www.domain.tw`?

Comment: was this solved? if so how?

Answer (score 1):

Route53 supports geolocation. This means that you can have multiple records for the same domain name but resolve to different addresses based on where the user is located. One record could point to your server in Taiwan and other record to your server in the US. Bother servers can even have the same domain name which is an important factor for HTTPS lookups.

Route53 geolocation is performed before the user goes to your web site. So this is not web page redirection.

[Route53 Routing Policies](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-policy.html)

[Route53 Geolocation Benchmarking](https://blog.takipi.com/aws-route-53-benchmarking-the-new-amazon-geolocation-policy/)

Comment: Then if I want to check user's location then direct to the right `url`, which service should I be looking at though?

Comment: Route53. Enable geolocation. Route53 will direct the user to the endpoint that you specify for that location. If you want your web server to do geolocation, then you will have to select a third party service and then do HTTP redirects.

Comment: @Dora you don't need to check the user's location.  You just need to configure both servers to handle requests for both domains.  If a request arrives at the US server for `Host: www.example.tw` you don't serve the TW content -- you know that's a US viewer, because Route 53 returns the IP of the US server to US viewers (for both domains)... so the US server should  redirect the viewer back to itself, at `www.example.com`.  They key here is that both servers respond to both hostnames, but if it's the "wrong" hostname, the server redirects to the other hostname, which is itself.